# Using .htaccess to redirect to a different URL based upon query strings

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I am currently redirecting URLs with a query string that includes ‘Googleb0t’ to the same page without the query string, via the htaccess file, by adding the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Googleb0t

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1? [L,NC,R=301]
```

So http://www.example.com/?Googleb0t would always redirect to http://www.example.com/

My question is how do you add multiple keywords to this directive in .htaccess if you have several parameters that need similar redirection?

If I also wanted URLs with different parameters, such as 'yah00' or 'bing' to 301 redirect the same way as URLs with 'Googleb0t' how would I do it?

Can this be accomplished in one single line of code?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Googleb0t|yah00|bing
```